# Second activity should have ImageView and TextView with different content depending on the selection in the first activity

Tags: android

I am working on an app that has some muscle workouts.

I want when each item in activity 1 is clicked to take me to activity 2
with different ImageView and TextView.
Is this possible ??

[image: pic]

Comment: Be more specific, what exactly do you want

Comment: Can Somebody show How ??

Comment: What's "abs workouts"? Is this Action Bar Sherlock, or are you working your abs in the gym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-** In your **1st Activity** create `ListView` to show your items.

**-** On the `onItemClickListener()` method of ListView, use `Intent` to go to the **2nd Activity.**

**-** Use `putExtra()` method of **Intent** to **put values** if need to be passed to the 2nd Activity, and **get them** on the **2nd Activity** using `getExtras()` method.

**Activity 1:**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);

                i.putExtra("value1","hello");
                i.putExtra("value2","hi");

                startActivity(i);



        });
```

**Activity 2:**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String index = intent.getExtras().getString("value1");
String value = intent.getExtras().getString("value2");
```

Comment: Thanks , this is hard ,Do you suggest any easier architecture for this app ??

Comment: @Jouni this is the most easiest way to do it... we can also do this by using `Bundle` ...but this way is far easier.

Comment: @Jouni Where is the image coming from..i mean whats the source of it... from ur SDCard , Web..etc ???

Comment: The image is in the app as a drawable

Comment: @Jouni suppose the image is stored in drawable as image_1.png then send this as String to the 2nd Activity and then use this String to get the image from the drawable........ and display it

Comment: I am  18 years old and confused whether to study Computer Science or Software Engineering ! any advice ?

Comment: @Jouni... Well i am from India, and i am an Engineer with Computer Science as discipline.... Software Engineering comes as a subject along with other subjects in the course. Computer Science gives a broader approach to various aspect of IT industry, like Programming, Networking, Micro-chip architecture..etc... and Software Engineering is a subject that deals with various aspect of Software Development. In India Computer Science Engineering and Software Engineering are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You have to use an Intent (with some data about the exercise) for the other Activity.

On the item onClick you create this intent and launch the Activity via startActivity(intent). In Activity 2 you read out the incoming Intent extra data and adjust the TextView/ImageView accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I am a beginner in android I don't know how to read the incoming data :(

Answer (score 1):

As commentators said "It is possible". It is possible via Intent used to start activity.  Use [Intent.putExtra(key,value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29) variations. These extras will be passed down to activity as [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) object. There you might fetch your extras. For example you might attach with;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HostActivity.this, SuccessorClass.class);

intent.putExtra("Extra key", extraData);

startActivity(intent);
```

and you might fetch the attached data with;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Object extraData = savedInstanceState.get("Extra key");
 }
```

Be sure to check put and get methods variations as they support most generic types. Cheers!